# how browsers intelligent on OS detection?

Tags: browser, intel

I am using a Linux PC (Ubuntu). Recently I went to install Dropbox on my PC and it was successful. The only matter right now I am thinking is simply how my browser helped Dropbox to forward me directly to a Linux based dropbox installation? My browser directly took me to the Linux installation page, How?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how Dropbox does it, but usually the browser sends a [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) string which tells the web server which brower you use, its version and the operating system. Here's an example:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22
```

You can check what your browser sends e.g. with `netcat`. Open up a terminal and open a TCP port:

```
nc -l -p 3456
```

Then point your browser to `localhost:3456` and check the result in the terminal. You could edit the User-Agent string to a typical one from another operating system and visit the Dropbox page, if the download changes then you have confirmed that Dropbox uses the User-Agent string to determine the OS.

Answer (score 2):

Your browser has a [user agent](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Agent) string which displays information about your operating system, screen resolution, etc.

You might want to try: [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com) or [showip.net](http://showip.net) to display your user agent.

This is sometimes considered as a privacy issue, you might want to check out [How trackable is my browser?](https://panopticlick.eff.org/).